# Using ncurses for pagination

Tags: linux, pagination, ncurses

I have implemented a custom shell using "clish". I need to add pagination of command output. I couldn't find any standalone libraries for this.

My understanding is that ncurses is used by many linux utilities to add pagination feature. But I could not find any helpful tutorials for this.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there any other simpler tool for this?

Comment: might be able to do something with dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to reuse an existing program, by making your shell run that as needed.  Actually, shells generally do *not* run pagers except as part of running arbitrary programs.  And any of the existing programs that you might be interested in are rather old and complex -- hard to use as a model for development.

If your shell must have a built-in pager, writing one is (like many programs), relatively simple to get something workable. But then it would grow according to your time/energy.

A quick look at the [NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) shows several simple programs.  The [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) includes a simple pager (actually file-viewer) `view.c`.